# PHP: Get input and send as attachment in phpmailer

Tags: php, email, attachment, send, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer To send images as attachments in emails.

But it's not working when I do this:

```
$photo = $_GET['photo_send'];
$photo = realpath($photo); 
var_dump($photo);
$mail->AddAttachment($photo);         // Add attachments
```

The image path shows in the url:

```
photo_send=images%2Ffullscreen%2F1.JPG%3Flol%3Dlol
```

When I put the path directly in the `AddAttachment` it works.

If anyone can suggest or give advise, i'd really appreciate it!

Comment: what is the path from where you getting images?

Comment: Your path is not OK. Put `$photo = realpath($photo); var_dump($photo);` between `$phone = ..` and `$mail->...`.

Comment: @chiragode the path is `images/fullscreen/image.jpg`

Comment: @Glavić it's still not working

Comment: @msbodetti: what did `var_dump` output?

Comment: @Glavić it's showing this message `bool(false) Message has been sent` and this in url `photo_send=images%2Ffullscreen%2F1.JPG%3Flol%3Dlol`

Comment: Like I said, your path is not OK. That is why `realpath()` returns `false`.

Comment: Put `var_dump($photo);` right after $_GET and tell us what it says.

Comment: It's saying `"images/fullscreen/1.JPG?lol=lol"`, but it's not coming in the email as attachment though @Glavić

Comment: Ah nevermind! :) It's working, I just needed to remove that `?lol=lol`. Add your answer and I will accept!

Comment: Just delete question ;-)

Comment: @Glavić I tried to delete it but someone answered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already said in comments, that your path is not OK.

You said, if you output `$photo` right after `$_GET` you get `images/fullscreen/1.JPG?lol=lol`

When you discovered that you need to remove `?lol=lol`, you found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$photo = images/fullscreen/$_GET['photo_send'];
$mail->AddAttachment($photo);
```

Comment: But the `photo_send` has `images/fullscreen`. Do you think it will be an issue?

Comment: then what about image name?